# Paging issues with Office 365 Calendar API

Tags: office365, outlook-restapi, office365api

I'm experiencing some weird issues with paging in the Office 365 REST API.

When fetching all events of a user in batches with the following request (of course, updating the skip parameter on every call):

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users%2Ftest1@eveoh.onmicrosoft.com/Events/?$orderby=Start&$select=ID&$top=50&$skip=100
```

**The user has 1000+ events in his calendar** and at some point I keep getting the same events every time. In this case after 666 events, ironically. The odata.nextLink is returned every time and the skip parameter is updated, but the events I that get returned are the same as on the last page. The routine ends up in a endless loop fetching more events of the same event.

Also, for some reason I sometimes receive a larger batch than requested. For example, upon the following request I get 470 events while 250 were expected.

```
https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users%2Ftest1@eveoh.onmicrosoft.com/Events/?$orderby=Start&$select=ID&$top=250
```

Has anyone experienced these problems too and if so, how did you solve the issue?

More examples of request/response traces demonstrating the problem [can be found here](https://gist.github.com/evpaassen/3d44e8a45f4bc8a88046).

Comment: have you tried to pull smaller batches, for example 10 or 20 records per batch.

Comment: check below my answer for the issue you have.

Comment: I haven't seen this issue. If the `$top` and `$skip` parameters aren't being honored, there's a bug somewhere in the service. It would be helpful if you can provide response headers from when this happens (and even more helpful if you can [instrument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn720380(v=exchg.150).aspx) your requests with `client-request-id` and `return-client-request-id` headers.

Comment: I created a Gist with traces [here](https://gist.github.com/evpaassen/3d44e8a45f4bc8a88046). It has been instrumented with the headers. It shows that the three requests skipping many events all result in the same events being returned. Skipping none (or not many) results in different events.

Comment: @JasonJohnston It seems like the CalendarView endpoint does work, in contrary to the Events endpoint. Using this endpoint may serve as a workaround for now. Did you get to look at the request/response traces?

Comment: Sorry, somehow I missed the notification of your prior comment! One question I have for you is how many events are there? Bear in mind that looking with OWA/Outlook will show you expanded occurrences of any recurring meetings, while the `Events` endpoint will not. `CalendarView` does expand recurring meetings and return each occurrence as a seperate event.

Comment: @JasonJohnston I don't know the exact number, but it will be somewhere between 1500~3000. All events were created through the API in the first place and are `SingleInstance`. I know about the difference between the endpoints, but for now this looks like the only feasible workaround to me.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I was able to reproduce this myself. I'll turn this over to our engineers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code to return exactly the number of records for the requested events.

```
// The code sample below demonstrates how to get events using the Office 365 unified API (Preview).
$.ajax('https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/Events/?$top=1', {
        headers: { 
           Authorization: 'Bearer {token:https://graph.microsoft.com/}',
            Accept: 'application/json;odata.metadata=none',
    }
}).then(function (response) {
        for (var i = 0; i < response.value.length; i++) {
            console.log('Event "' + response.value[i].Subject + '"');
        }
        console.log('\n' + 'Full JSON response:')
        console.log(response);
    }).fail(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Also, if you want to test this out:

1) Go to the below url (o365 sandbox api) -> Code Samples -> Get events -> and select your language either C# or JS:

https://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/

2) Login with your o365 creds.

3) Change the query by adding ?top=1 for the top records you are requesting.

4) you will see that the api returns exactly the requested number of records.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem I'm facing does not simply occur with every user, so I don't think there's something wrong with the requests I make (see above). It rather seems to be a bug with the skip parameter in the API, under some conditions. Some explanation on when this occurs or suggestions for a workaround would be great.

Comment: Avoid using $skip and use $filter instead and get events per day, it should be minimal per day and then you can pull data per day. let me know if this works with you.

Comment: While this might work, this is not very efficient as I'd need to send one request per day for each user. This would be 365 calls per user to fetch a calendar for one year. Not very scalable. And even then I don't have the guarantee all events have been returned.